# setup SQL server to use multiple servers which can be referred by one name

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to set up two SQL servers but they should be accessible from only one name

e.g.
I want two sql server instances QA1 and QA2 but there should be one proxy sql server QA which can decide (depending on incoming request) to redirect request to either QA1 or QA2

QA1 will have multiple databases e.g. A, B, C
QA2 will have multiple databases e.g. D, E, F

and all these databases can be used when any connection string points to server "QA"

Comment: There is no such thing called load balancer in Sql  server? Why you want to have setup like this? Why don't you have one server with all the database on it?

Comment: Why do you think you need such a thing? Are you confusing load balancing with clustering perhaps? Availability Groups? Database Mirroring? Read-only replicas?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to build a smart client wrapper which maintains the list of servers and has a Strategy to decide which Server to use to execute a command
 There is another option of exposing the same functionality as a server.